# Android studio IDE change persian comment font

Tags: java, fonts, farsi, android-studio-4.0, android-ide

In Android studio 4 IDE, hardly to read the Persian comment with the default font. I tried use another font in setting but no effected.

[image]

How I can change comment font in Persian. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally solved my problem by unchecking the Italic checkbox

[image]

And comment font changed to normal!

[image]